# How to get the current state of the page in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page which contains many links and upon expansion of each link i have grid and button.The button when clicked will be redirected to an new page where some process is done and returns a message via querystring.My problem is how to show the message returned from new page exactly in the previous state(example: the toggling/expansion showing grid and button).How to do that??

Comment: Is this question about how to access variables in the querystring?

Comment: No...I wanted to use the querystring value in the previous page in the same state before the page was redirected to new page

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to maintain state of which link was clicked (by passing it to the new page in the query string) and when you return from the new page you'll have to pass it back (in the query string ) so you can reconstruct the page as you desire (with the area relative to that link expanded).

Comment: In the first Page you redirect to the NewPage.aspx?LinkId=2. In the New Page you redirect to FirstPage.aspx?LinkId=2&Msg=Sucess. When the First Page is loaded you'll have to interpret this values and rebuild it accordingly to the Link you wish to expand and to the Message you wish to present.